# Iterating over an instance method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm retrieving data from a web page. There are multiple occurrences of similarly-structured `important` blocks, on which I will use more methods through iteration. Is there a way to make something like what's below work?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class Scraper      
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def name
    @name ||= doc.at_css(".currentverylong").text
  end

  def important
    @important = doc.css(".main_entry")
  end

  important.each do |item|
    define_method(:artist) do
      @artist ||= item.at_css(".list_artist").text
    end

    define_method(:title) do
      @title ||= item.at_css(".list_album").text
    end
  end

  private
  attr_reader :url

  def doc
    @doc ||= Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  end
end

scraper = Scraper.new( #url
puts scraper.name
puts "#{scraper.artist} \"#{scraper.title}\" "
```

The way it is now, the error is that `important` is undefined. Eliminating `important` and replacing it with with `doc.css(."main_entry").each do |item|` has the same problem. Which also leads another question. Why does a method like below accept `doc` just fine?

```
def name
  @name ||= doc.at_css(".currentverylong").text
end
```

**UPDATE**
As somebody has mentioned here and also in response to another related question on SO, the fact that `important` is being repeatedly over-written is the problem here. Could somebody explain what exactly happens in this process and what leads to the `undefined local variable or method` for `important`?

Comment: What context are you trying to `important.each` in? `important` is an *instance* method after all...

Comment: Please provide a complete, i.e. runnable example.

Comment: updated, eventually the scraped data will be added to a database, but for now I'm just printing it to the console.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want important to come back nil, you could just tack on a default empty array value to your `important` method.

```
def important
  @important ||= doc.css(".main-entry") || []
end
```

If there's a possibility `doc` will be nil (not sure how you're loading that url), you can use `try` to get to that empty array statement.

```
def important
  @important ||= doc.try(:css, ".main-entry") || []
end
```

This will guarantee that `important` yields an array object.

Comment: Hmm, neither of the two options fix it. I have updated the original post, if you have a moment to look at it and suggest something else. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of 'not working' are you seeing? Looking at your update, it looks like you're iterating through an 'important' array and defining a method for each one, which won't work because you'll overwrite your previous method during each iteration.

What is the intended output? An array of artists and albums scraped from a given url?

Comment: It is the exact same `undefined local variable or method` error. And yes, that is the intended output exactly. Right now, I just want to see the output printed to the console, but after I can see that that works, I want to save the scraped data to a database. How does the over-writing part get in the way of achieving this. Once the code has gone through one of many `important` blocks, over-writing it should theoretically be fine, if one has been printed to console or saved to db, it's no longer needed after that.